# How to set amount from table as an event using itext?

Tags: templates, events, event-handling, itext

May I know how to set amount that I insert into a Pdf Table as an event? I need the item amount to get the total by page and display on the bottom of the page. But what I did now is I set the amount during the SQL execution where the data will directly insert into a table. Once the table is complete then add into document. As result, I get the whole amount for the item, not the item by page event though I try to print the total by page using `onEndPage()`. I want to create the table on a template but I don't know to insert table into template and how to retrieve the row line number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `TotalAmount` object and two different cell events.

The `TotalAmount` object should have one variable (e.g. `amount`) and two or three methods: `addAmount()`, `getAmount()` and `resetAmount()`.

Create the first type of cell event with the `TotalAmount` object and the *amount* as parameters. Add the *amount* to the `TotalAmount` in the *layout()* method. This method will be triggered when the body cells are drawn.

Create the second type of cell event with the `TotalAmount` object as parameter. Use this cell event for an empty footer cell. Use the value returned by `getAmount()` to draw that value in the `layout()` method. Use the `resetAmount()` method if the total shown in the footer isn't cumulative.

When you create the table, the table object isn't aware of paginatin. The events are triggered only at the moment the cells are drawn, NOT at the moment you create the table. That's why you can't add the amount at the moment you create the table.

Comment: Thanks @bruno. I have tried to create the table using cellEvent, but then the whole data is been display on just 1 page. I try to get the amount only but then the data is not showing.  I have try to understand your example such as Calendar and RunLengthEvent but I couldn't make it. I want to implement the same method for page number but I can't estimate number of items that will display on each page because some of the items might have a long description. Plus, I unable to get number of item  and the amount.

Comment: You studied the examples, but did you read the book? It can be hard to understand the examples without any additional explanation. Als you don't need to know the number of items that will display on each page. That's the beauty of the solution I described. I'm sorry if you didn't understand it. The only other way I can help you, is by writing you an example, but that's not what SO is about, is it?

Comment: so far this is the output that I manage to get, [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B08QoW0a6qyLZ3VsOXdURXl2dzA). the only thing that left is to get the subtotal. I will try my best to solve the solution. if not, I will try to reach you again. I have set to skip the header "Sub Total Carried Forward" using table.setSkipFirstHeader(true); but it still display the row. but the footer is working... Thanks again :)

Comment: As soon as I find the time, I'll make an example. I can't guarantee anything though. I'm pretty busy with some other work.

Comment: I'll look forward for it. Hope that you can let me know about it. Meanwhile, I will keep trying and try to get other reference. Thanks

Comment: hi,,

I want to ask again,, I created the cellLayout() and 2 different table.
Table 1 : to store the content
Table 2 : to store the accumulative total of items
cell Layout : suppose to display SubTotal

My Problem is, the >cellLayout display the whole total, and it is displaying on only one page.
table 2 data is written using >writeSelectedRows() method, and is it also displaying on the same page. How can I set the table 2 data to make sure the data display according to the page size and get the same row with table 1 data?